# Import CSV creating nodes with no properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a set of labeled nodes using IMPORT CSV like so:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/D:/OpenData/ProKB/tmp/ErrLink.csv" as line 
CREATE (e:ErrLink {kbid:line.Kbid, errnum:line.Errnum })
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
"Kbid:string","Errnum:string"
"S000001080","64"
"S000001096","129"
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm creating nodes, and they're all property-less. If I get rid of the **:string** suffixes on the header fields, then the load works.

This is contrary to what Chapter 29.1 of the docs says:

*29.1. CSV file header format*

*The header row of each data source specifies how the fields should be interpreted. The same delimiter is used for the header row as for the rest of the data.*

*The header contains information for each field, with the format: **name:field_type**. The **name** is used as the property key for values, and ignored in other cases. The following **field_type** settings can be used for both nodes and relationships:*

*Property value Use one of int, long, float, double, boolean, byte, short, char, string to designate the data type. If no data type is given, this defaults to string. To define an array type, append [] to the type. Array values are by default delimited by a ;, but a different delimiter can be specified.*

Is this functionality not working, or is it restricted to just the import tool and not the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section of the documentation is for the [Import Tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool.html), which is different than the Cypher language's [Load CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) clause.

If you are using the latter, that special header format is not documented, and apparently not supported.